# Determine if a string has inner word boundaries

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching, string-matching

I use following g to determine if word appears in a text, enforcing word boundaries:

```
 if ( Pattern.matches(".*\\b" + key + "\\b.*", text) ) {
    //matched
 }
```

This would match *book* on *text-book* but not on *facebook*.

Now, I would like to to do the reverse: **determine if the input text has a word boundary inside**.

E.g. `mutually-collaborative` (CORRECT, there is a word boundary inside) and `mutuallycollaborative` (WRONG, as there is no word boundary inside).

If the boundary was a *punctuation* this will work:

```
if( Pattern.matches("\\p{Punct}", text) ) { //check punctuations
        //has punctuation
}
```

I would like to check for word boundaries in general , e.g. '-', etc.

Any idea?

Comment: You should add examples since your question is unclear.

Comment: If you want to find words that contain `key`, just use `"(?s).*(?:\\B" + key + "|" + key + "\\B).*"` (with `.matches()`).

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte what's unclear? I would like to match any word boundary. I have given example of hyphen ('-') and punctuation marks. These are examples of word boundaries but I am looking for a general case.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, I am not looking for a particular key but to determine if a string has a word boundary.

Comment: Then you just need `"\\b"` pattern and use with `Matcher#find()`. `\b` asserts a position at a word boundary `(^\w|\w$|\W\w|\w\W)`. **See [this demo](http://ideone.com/StpnvA)**.

Comment: What the difference between matching whether a text contains word vs whether a text contains a word boundary? Aren't the two the same match?

Comment: Also, I think you can be looking for [this](http://ideone.com/5GAQk3).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew the example at http://ideone.com/StpnvA doesn't work. It returned true for both *mutually-collaborative* (CORRECT) and *mutuallycollaborative* (WRONG)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew the example at http://ideone.com/5GAQk3 uses a particular key. This is similar to the example I gave in the question. It's not what I am looking for. What I need is a general case for word boundary, similar to the general case for punctuation I gave in the question.

Comment: I think you are looking to exclude two alternatives in `\b` construct, `^\w` and `\w$`. Check [this demo](http://ideone.com/Y0TjES) with `"(?U)(?:\\W\\w|\\w\\W)"` regex.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, `(?U)\\b\\w|\\w\\b` doesn't work either. Tried it on *mutuallycollaborative* it returned `true` while it should return `false`

Comment: I know, I deleted that comment, and am about to post an answer.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, the example at http://ideone.com/Y0TjES works! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to check if a given string contains a word boundary *inside* the string. Note that `\b` matches at the beginning and end of a non-empty string. Thus, you need to exclude those alternatives. Just use

```
"(?U)(?:\\W\\w|\\w\\W)"
```

This way, you will make sure a string contains a combination of a word and a non-word characters.

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/Y0TjES):

```
String s = "mutuallyexclusive";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?U)(?:\\W\\w|\\w\\W)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
if (matcher.find()){
    System.out.println(matcher.group() + " word boundary found!"); 
} else {
    System.out.println("Word boundary NOT found in " + s);  
}
```

Just some reference on what a [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) can match:

> There are three different positions that qualify as word boundaries:
>
> - Before the first character in the string, if the first character is a word character.
> - After the last character in the string, if the last character is a word character.
> - Between two characters in the string, where one is a word character and the other is not a word character.

So, with `\w\W|\W\w`, we exclude the first 2 situations.

Comment: What's the meaning of `(?U)` ?

Comment: This is an inline [`Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS) modifier making `\w` and `\W` Unicode aware.